# Setting fetchSize in groovy Sql

Tags: sql, jdbc, groovy, fetch, limit

I am using groovy sql (2.4.4). But I could not figure out how to set fetchSize and scroll the results.

I use `sql.setResultSetType(ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY)` but queries with `sql.rows(sqlQuery)` returns all the data at the same time and this is really slow. I want to fetch the data like we do in normal jdbc queries.

Setting maxRows is not really an option because I have to query too many times, but fetchSize would be a good option.

In groovy sql documentation(http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.4/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html) I see that:

> A facade over Java's normal JDBC APIs providing greatly simplified resource management and result set handling.

But no information given about fetching.
How can I set fetchSize ?

Thank You!

Comment: You may consider adding filtering result to get the desired data if not already doing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For **`fetchSize`**, this seems to be the only option,

- [`withStatement()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.4/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#withStatement(groovy.lang.Closure)); which takes a `Closure`

An example here,

```
 sql.withStatement { stmt -> stmt.fetchSize = 50 }
```

For **`maxResult`**, there are few options available,

- use overloaded [`rows()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.4/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#rows(groovy.lang.GString,%20int,%20int)) method that takes a `maxRows` param, or
- you could use, [`asList()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.4/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#asList(java.lang.String,%20java.sql.ResultSet,%20int,%20int,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) method that takes a `maxRows` param, or
- use [`eachRow()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/2.4.4/html/api/groovy/sql/Sql.html#eachRow(groovy.lang.GString,%20int,%20int,%20groovy.lang.Closure)) that takes a `maxRows` param

**NB:** There are quite a number of overloaded methods named `rows(..)`, `asList(..)`, and `eachRow(..)`.

Comment: withStatement does exactly what I need. Thank you